# Kotlin set text method not working

Tags: android, kotlin

What is wrong in below line for kotlin :

```
answerTv!!.setText( firstNum + " > " + secondNum);
```

This line given me error. What's wrong in above line?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Do you have another textView in other files that its id is answerTv too?

Comment: Error : None of the functions can be called with arguments supplied....

Comment: val result = (firstNum + " > " + secondNum) as String
answerTv?.setText( result);
Make sure answerTV is not null , if not used binding mechaninsam.

you can check for null 
print(answerTV)

Comment: For not null I am using !! operator.

answerTv!!

Problem occur inside of setText method near + operator.

Answer (score 4):

```
answerTv.text = "$firstNum  >  $secondNum";
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin tries to identify the type of object from first operand if "+" is used as concatenation. Try using "" (blank stirng) as first argument.

```
answerTv!!.text = "" + firstNum + " > " + secondNum
```

or

```
answerTv!!.setText("" + firstNum + " > " + secondNum);
```

Comment: I used but still same problem.

Comment: Please try now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Birju is perfectly correct. Another option (rather less elegant) is to get explicitly the string value of each number:

```
answerTv.text = firstNum.toString() + " > " + secondNum.toString()
```